# LCDS with ColdFusion without Flex

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, blazeds, lcds

Is there a way to do BlazeDS/LCDS and ColdFusion polling without the need to use Flex to connect to them to achieve pseudo-"realtime"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Javascript, poll data every n seconds?

or... http://www.ape-project.org/